# How to merge two documents into one document by inserting sub-documents on pyspark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I have a big problem and hope to be clear in explaining what would like to do.
I'm trying to get a Stream-Stream structure on pyspark (Spark Structured Streaming) and I would like to update the same document when get new data from the scraping in Kafka.

These are examples of JSON that are sent, on localhost, on MongoCompass:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("28276465847392747")
id: reply
Company: reply
Value:{

    Date: 20-05-2020
    Last_Hour_Contract: 09.12.25
    Last_Hour: 09.14.30
    Price: 16.08 
    Quantity: 8000 
    Medium_Price: 8.98 
    Min_Price: 8.98 
    Max_Price: 20.33
    News: { id_news: Reply_20-05-20
           title_news: "titolo news"
           text: "text"
           date: 20-05-2020
           hour: 09:13:00
           subject: Reply
        }

     }
}
{
_id: ObjectId("28276465847392747")
id: reply
Company: reply
Value:{

    Date: 20-05-2020
    Last_Hour_Contract: 09.12.25
    Last_Hour: 09.14.30
    Price: 17.78 
    Quantity: 9000 
    Medium_Price: 67.98 
    Min_Price: 8.98 
    Max_Price: 20.33
    News: { id_news: Reply_20-05-20
           title_news: "title_news"
           text: "text"
           date: 20-05-2020
           hour: 09:13:00
           subject: Reply
        }

    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to merge the various documents (Based on Company_Name = "Name_Company") into one document when new data arrives.

The setting of the JSON document I would like is the following:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("3333884747656565"),
id: reply
Date: 21-05-2020
Company: Reply
Value:{
    Date: 20-05-2020
    Last_Hour_Contract: 09.12.25
    Last_Hour: 09.14.30
    Price: 16.08
    Quantity: 8000
    Medium_Price: 8.98
    Min_Price: 8.98
    Max_Price: 20.33
    News: {id_news: Reply_20-05-20
           title_news: "title news..."
           text: "text..."
           date: 20-05-2020
           hour: 09:13:00
           subject: Reply
        }
    Date: 21-05-2020    
    Last_Hour_Contract: 09.12.25
    Last_Hour: 09.16.50
    Price: 16.68
    Quantity: 7000
    Medium_Price: 8.98
    Min_Price: 8.98
    Max_Price: 20.33
    News: {id_news: Reply_20-05-20
           title_news: "title news..."
           text: "text..."
           date: 21-05-2020
           hour: 09:14:00
           subject: Reply
        }
   }
}
```

I also insert an image to make you understand better (I hope the 2 arrows are understandable):

[image]

How could this be done using Pyspark? Thanks

This is my code:

```
def writeStreamer(sdf):
    sdf.select("id_Borsa","NomeAzienda","Valori_Di_Borsa")  \
    .dropDuplicates(["id_Borsa","NomeAzienda","Valori_Di_Borsa"]) \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
    .start() 


def foreach_batch_function(sdf, epoch_id):
    sdf.write \
        .format("mongo") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DataManagement.Data") \
        .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DataManagement.Data") \
        .save() #"com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource"


df_borsa = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker) \
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
          .option("subscribe","Reply_borsa") \
          .load() \
          .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 

df_news = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_broker) \
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
          .option("subscribe","Reply_news") \
          .load() \
          .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") 


df_borsa = df_borsa.withColumn("Valori_Di_Borsa",F.struct(F.col("Data"),F.col("PrezzoUltimoContratto"),F.col("Var%"),F.col("VarAssoluta"),F.col("OraUltimoContratto"),F.col("QuantitaUltimo"),F.col("QuantitaAcquisto"),F.col("QuantitaVendita"),F.col("QuantitaTotale"),F.col("NumeroContratti"),F.col("MaxOggi"),F.col("MinOggi")))

df_news = df_news.withColumn("News",F.struct(F.col("id_News"),F.col("TitoloNews"),F.col("TestoNews"),F.col("DataNews"),F.col("OraNews")))

# Apply watermarks on event-time columns
dfWithWatermark = df_borsa.select("id_Borsa","NomeAzienda","StartTime","Valori_Di_Borsa").withWatermark("StartTime", "2 hours") # maximal delay

df1WithWatermark = df_news.select("SoggettoNews","EndTime").withWatermark("EndTime", "3 hours") # maximal delay

# Join with event-time constraints
sdf = dfWithWatermark.join(df1WithWatermark,expr(""" 
      SoggettoNews = NomeAzienda AND
      EndTime >= StartTime AND
      EndTime <= StartTime + interval 1 hours
      """),
       "leftOuter").withColumn("Valori_Di_Borsa",F.struct(F.col("Valori_Di_Borsa.*"),F.col("News"))) 


query = writeStreamer(sdf)

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

sdf_printschema():

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is, use `group` operator to group documents by `Company` field and add the `value` object of each of the grouped documents into newly formed array field `values` by using `$push` operator.

So, the mongo implementation of the above will be like below:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '$Company',
        id: {$first: '$id'},
        date: {$first: '$first'},
        values: {$push: '$value'}
    }
}])
```

You can easily convert the above aggregation to PySpark implementation.

You'l need to do something like below:

```py
pipeline = "{'$group': {'_id': '$Company', 'id': {'$first': '$id'}, 'date': {'$first': '$first'}, 'values': {'$push': '$value'}}}"
df = spark.read.format("mongo").option("pipeline", pipeline).load()
df.show()
```

**Note:** I am not an expert in PySpark, but you can easily convert it to the required implementation.

Comment: On mongocompass it works perfectly! but on pyspark not yet ...
I tried to insert your pipeline on the foreach_batch_function here but as soon as I enter MongoCompass it gives me back the two or more documents

Comment: I would like to be exactly what you wrote, however as soon as I enter MongoCompass nothing happens ... I tried to insert your pipeline in different points of my code but nothing.

Comment: I am more unfortunate than you. I don't even know PySpark. If you want, I will remove this answer and upvote this question, so that you will get an answer from an expert? And, it will be a learning for me also. (But, I just guided you, though)

Comment: All right! If you can do it you would do me a huge favor, thanks